# ValueError: empty range for randrange() (1,1, 0)

Tags: python, random

I'm writing that takes percent for hitting the number  from user and checks if it hit the number,
and returns true or false.
But I'm still getting this error

```
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (1,1, 0)
```

Can you help me ?

```
def PercentConvertion(Percent):
IntPercent = int(Percent / 100)
Chance = random.randint(1,IntPercent)
purpose = int(IntPercent / 2)
hit = None
if Chance == purpose:
    hit = True
else:
    hit = False
return hit
```

Comment: Is that the formatting in your code?

Comment: BTW `return Chance == purpose` could fully replace the 6 lines at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Your starting number is 1, and the ending number is 1. Therefore, you are asking you any numbers between 1 and 1. However, there are no numbers between 1 and 1, hence the error. It's like asking for a number between 2 and 2: there are none. Therefore, you get your error because there aren't any numbers it can produce. In order for randrange to work, the first number needs to be at least 2 less or more than the second number e.g. `randrange(1,3, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

random.randint(start, stop) is true when we put stop > start.

PercentConvertion(10) then IntPercent is 0 so the function shows ValueError.